# I cant find the device name for pcap.Openlive

Tags: go, pcap, gopacket

I'm trying to capture packets in using `gopackets` and `pcap` but i cant find the device name for the function `pcap.OpenLive`.

I tried putting `wlan0` as the device name and I got the error

> Error opening adapter: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (123)

Comment: [Are you on Windows?](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35095)

Comment: yeah i fixed it thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried putting wlan0 as the device name and I got the error

That's a Linux-style device name.  Other operating systems have different naming conventions.

The naming conventions on Windows, with WinPcap or Npcap, are... difficult.  The names include a hex representation of a 128-bit GUID.

You should try using [FindAllDevs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap#FindAllDevs) to get a list of devices and show devices with both their names and descriptions, although the description may not be all that helpful.